# How do you use Xamarin.UITest to sign an apk for Android 11?

Tags: android, android-11, xamarin.uitest

I want to use a Xamarin.UITest project to test my application (and then upload the test to the App Center).

I am writing code in Visual Studio Community 2019 version 16.9.4 and want to build against the latest Android version.

When I try to run the tests locally I get the error:

> System.Exception : Mono Shared Runtime is not supported. This can be resolved by **changing the project configuration** or using a **Release build**.

With regards to ***project configuration***:

- I get this whether pointing to Android target framework version 11 (latest) or 10.
- In the project properties of my Android project (Android Options -> Packaging Properties) [as per this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MP7CO.png) the obvious solution to uncheck the 'Use Shared Runtime' option is not available.
- Manually adding the property `AndroidUseSharedRuntime` to the `.csproj` doesn't seem to make a difference.

With regards to a ***Release build***:

- I have tried running against the `.apk` built in Release mode on target framework version 10, and it works! But I want to use version 11...
- When I have a target framework version of 11, I get this error on the test:

  > Failed to execute: C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s emulator-5554
  > install -g
  > "C:\Users{name}\AppData\Local\Temp\uitest\a-2351CD300830FF81600819C12D0457454DDA69A2\final-9EB410B8BE4AE99B420FA491930368F065D971A1.apk" - exit code: 1

  > adb: failed to install C:\Users{name}\AppData\Local\Temp\uitest\a-2351CD300830FF81600819C12D0457454DDA69A2\final-9EB410B8BE4AE99B420FA491930368F065D971A1.apk: Failure [INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_NO_CERTIFICATES: Scanning Failed.: No signature found in package of version 2 or newer for package {com.package.name}]
  > Performing Streamed Install

  I've seen a couple of posts about this message [(leads here)](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/11/behavior-changes-11#minimum-signature-scheme), and Android 11+ needs to be signed differently but I expected (hope) VS would do it automatically as part of its signing with that target version.

So, I have 2 questions - maybe it's an either/or:

1. Am I missing something in the project configuration that means I don't need to do a separate Release build locally to create the `.apk` before running my tests?
2. How can I get Xamarin.UITest to sign the app with the signature required for target framework version 11?